# Para que serve os dois pontos duplos (::) ?

Tags: php

Vejo em algumas classes algo parecido com o seguinte:

***Classe  ilustrativa***

```
class Carro
{
    private static $quantidade = 5;

    public function getQuantidade()
    {
        return self::$quantidade;
    }

    public function comprar()
    {

        self::$quantidade--;
    }
}
```

O que quero saber é o seguinte, o operador `self` chama a variável usando dois pontos **`self::`**. Afinal, para que serve esse tipo de chamada? Por que foi usado dessa forma e não usando o operador `$this` =>  **`$this->$quantidade`** ?

Comment: As duas perguntas já devem responder bastante, mas resumindo: Tem como finalidade fazer chamadas à métodos e propriedades estáticas e constantes da classe.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters obrigado, irei dar uma lida :)

Comment: Resumindo  o double column serve para acessar membros estáticos de uma classe